# How to get Data from INNER JOIN request in Yii2?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I am trying to get data from this query:

```
SELECT threads.thread_id
     , threads.thread_name
     , threads.author_id
     , users.name
  FROM threads
  JOIN users
    ON threads.author_id = users.id 
 ORDER 
    BY thread_id
 LIMIT 5
```

It works in phpmyadmin just fine, but when i try it with Yii2 with the code below:

```
 $query = Threads::find();

    $pagination = new Pagination([
        'defaultPageSize' => 5,
        'totalCount' => $query->count(),
    ]);

    $threads = $query->select(['threads.thread_id','threads.thread_name','threads.author_id','users.name'])
        ->from('threads')
        ->join('INNER JOIN', 'users', 'threads.author_id = users.id')
        ->orderBy('thread_id')
        ->offset($pagination->offset)
        ->limit($pagination->limit)
        ->all();
```

And then in the view accessing $thread->name, it gives me an error, saying there's no such field, while every field from 'threads' table works fine.

```
<?php foreach ($threads as $thread): ?>
<li>
    <?= var_dump($thread)?>
    <a href=" <?= Url::to(['thread/view', 'id' => $thread->thread_id])?>"><?=$thread->thread_name?></a>
    <?= Html::encode("{$thread->thread_id} ({$thread->thread_name})") ?>:
    <p>Author: <?=$thread->name?></p>
</li>
```

What is wrong?

UPDATE: Exact Error message

```
yii\base\ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\YiiForum\views\thread\index.php:14
```

UPDATE: var_dump($thread)

```
object(app\models\Threads)#82 (13) { ["thread_id":"app\models\Threads":private]=> NULL ["thread_name":"app\models\Threads":private]=> NULL ["author_id":"app\models\Threads":private]=> NULL ["_attributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=> array(3) { ["thread_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["thread_name"]=> string(30) "Привет, как дела?" ["author_id"]=> int(1) } ["_oldAttributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=> array(3) { ["thread_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["thread_name"]=> string(30) "Привет, как дела?" ["author_id"]=> int(1) } ["_related":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=> array(0) { } ["_relationsDependencies":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=> array(0) { } ["_errors":"yii\base\Model":private]=> NULL ["_validators":"yii\base\Model":private]=> NULL ["_scenario":"yii\base\Model":private]=> string(7) "default" ["_events":"yii\base\Component":private]=> array(0) { } ["_eventWildcards":"yii\base\Component":private]=> array(0) { } ["_behaviors":"yii\base\Component":private]=> array(0) { }
```

Comment: update your question and show the exact error message

Comment: update your question and show the result for  var_dump($thread)

Comment: can you try adding the `users.id` to the select clause in the query `$query->select(['threads.thread_id','threads.thread_name','threads.author_id','users.name', 'users.id'])` and you dont need the `->from('threads')` just remove it `threads` will be selected automatically you are using `Threads` model for the query not `new \yii\db\Query()`.

Comment: Which line is in `views\thread\index.php:14`?

Comment: @rob006 its `<p>Author: <?=$thread->name?></p>`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam in that case error message(*Trying to get property of non-object*) looks invalid - `$thread` already worked as object in two above lines.

Comment: welll..... you are right there @rob006

Answer (score -2):

may be its can useful

```
$query = new Query();
    $query->select([
        'c.id as car_id',
        'c.name_ru as car_name',
        'c.slug_ru as car_slug',
        'cp.price as price',
        'cp.sztype_id as sztype_id',
    ])->from(['c'=>'c_car'])
        ->leftJoin(['cp'=>'c_car_price'],'cp.car_id=c.id')
        ->where(['c.collection_id'=>$collections[0]['collection_id'],'cp.show_price'=>self::ACTIVE_ONE])
        ->limit(6)
        ->all();
```

Comment: This answer is completely unrelated to question.